# css3 :hover animation not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, css-animations

I've created a CSS3 code that created a page flipping effect.

With three encapsulated div tags, first a div encapsulates the plain page and sets the perspective and transform-style. The second div which contains the page is then rotated3d through the X-axis some degrees (I need an isometric perspective) and finally the inner div creates the page with a determinated color and size attributes.

This inner div has a :hover pseudo with an animation property, which indicates the transformation to do (in this case, flipping itself through the Y-axis). For this purpouse there's as well a keyframe with a transformation-origin and the rotate3d attributes.

For some reason this works neat on Chrome webkit, but not on Firefox. In Chrome once the hover is done it keeps flipping until the page is totally turn over, even when the mouse is not anymore on the page due to the rotation. In Firefox however it makes a small flip movement, but goes back to its initial state inmediately, even if the mouse is still on the page.

I've tried with animation-play-state: running; on the :hover pseudo, but neither works.

Any help? I can assure the -moz syntax is good as in -webkit. Thanks!!

Comment: can you please share the css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: [There you go](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackMetal/8usqH/). I found on further testing that moving the outer div some px to the right makes it work almost everytime, but not always. Still, it looks that running it on Firefox is much slower and less smooth than on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `width` and `height` for the `.box` element and use it for hovering instead of the `.rotateaux` element:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 90px;
    ...
 }

.box:hover .rotateaux {
```

Interestingly when using `rotate3d` Firefox rotates the element in the wrong direction as soon as specifying an angle >= `180°`, ignoring the `-` sign, not sure what's the cause of this, so I've used `rotateY` in my example which Firefox handles correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7Chp/

```
<div class="book">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="rotateaux"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.book {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 80px;
    right: 300px;

    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
       -moz-perspective: 300px;
            perspective: 300px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
       -moz-perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
            perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 90px;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transform: rotateX(70deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateX(70deg);
            transform: rotateX(70deg);
}
.rotateaux {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 90px;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
            transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.box:hover .rotateaux {
    -webkit-animation: example 1.75s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
       -moz-animation: example 1.75s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
            animation: example 1.75s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes example {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
             transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
             transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as a charm. Thanks!! Still, I can't see why my code is not working on Firefox. 

However, looks like there's an aliasing problem on Firefox. On the other hand it works even when the page is in the screen limits.

I can't vote up for a lack of reputation but so far so good.

Comment: You're welcome. I also don't know what exactly the problem is in Firefox, if you stop the cursor fast enough it works fine, so If I were to guess I'd say it's a bug.